# What is the best template-engine to update in real time your website with express?

Tags: knockout.js, express, pug

I am using express and i have heard about [KnockOutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) witch allow you to bind dom elements and your javascript object.

I am using JADE template engine with express. I think there might tricky to use both jade and knockOut.

To your opinion, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at nodestream which is realtime templating build by the Express team based on JADE. I am building a similar thing based on swig.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/nodestream

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not really a Knockout guy neither a proficient Jade user but its probably doable though I wouldn't go this way but at the end of the day it's only a question of choice and support.

The adequate solution for me would be to use mustache templates compiled with Hogan and use either Backbone or Spine as an MVVM. However lately I'm doing a lot of Ruby instead of node and I found myself using Eco on the client side because it uses the exact same syntax as Erb so my templates are reusable on both side as they should be with mustache but the overhead is way lower and the rendering is a bit faster than having to compile a whole different templating language.

However, as I have said it's only a question of choice and how people in your team will be able to be efficient with the tool you use. That's why I tend to avoid templating language which abstract a lot of things such as Jade or Haml because the overhead could be too high for people only doing HTML (even if it's rare those days) rather than having a small set of template specific code wrapped around HTML.

Comment: Hi, welcome o Stackoverflow. Try create a example of what you are saying with code when possible

Comment: I'll cook up some examples in a git repo after work if that's necessary.

Comment: You can use jsFiddle or JSbin for that :D

Comment: It's great for client-side code but doesn't provide a way to write server code AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Jade is fully compatible with KnockoutJS, I actually prefer the syntax resulting from using both.

```
label Description
            input(data-bind="value: description")
```

Its very clean, and I have used it before successfully.

Comment: One caveat to this is that if you want to use Knockout comment-syntax (which is sometimes necessary), it is a bit ugly with Jade.